# Replace Text in P Element on Rollover of another Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't believe that I'm having so much trouble with this; thought the first result in Google would do it. I'm just trying to be able to roll over an image and replace the text in a p element (Select a Module) with another pre-defined text. When my mouse leaves the image, the p element goes back to a default text (Select a Module).

This is what I have, but no response from the script ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('p#module_1').bind('mouseover', function() {
        $('p#module_main').text('Module 1');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="module_main">Select a Module</p>

<p id="module_1">Icon 1</p>
<p id="module_2">Icon 2</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you using double `});` . Just delete one. And put it in $(document).ready(function(){...})

Comment: syntax error  additional `});` in script tag :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is when you close after your `bind()` function. You need add a DOM ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p#module_1').bind('mouseover', function() {
        $('p#module_main').text('Module 1');
    });
});
```

[See this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0kdg7f6/1/)

Comment: Thank you Vincent, it's working, but what would I need to add to get it to reset to "Select a Module" when I roll away from an icon? Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

(1) `.bind()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and replaced with `.on()`. The syntax is virtually identical.

(2) `.on()` is only required for elements that have been added to the DOM after it was already rendered. In other words, if you inject new content to the page after initial display then you need to use `.on()`. Otherwise, not necessary. See the `mouseout` example in below code. *By the way, this is called `event delegation` and is worth reading about.*

(3) As Vincent has already pointed out, you need `document.ready` to make your code wait for all DOM elements to be present before attempting to bind event-watching-code to those elements. Otherwise, the javascript could execute *before* those elements exist and the bindings won't succeed *(how does code bind to something that does not yet exist?)* - which is what you were seeing. Mouseover was not being detected because the code was not watching the `p` tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('mouseover', '#module_1', function() {
        $('#module_main').text('Module 1');
    });
  
    $('#module_1').mouseout(function() {
        $('#module_main').text('ICON 1');
    });

}); //END document.ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="module_main">Select a Module</p>

<p id="module_1">Icon 1</p>
<p id="module_2">Icon 2</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is not working is because the bind function is being called before your p tags are loaded into the dom. That is why the above answer works, it delays running the bind function until after all of the html elements have been loaded into the dom. If you move your script tag down below the p tags (and remove the last line in your script tag) it will work too because of the sequence of events.